# Build a 2 dimensional array in jquery, loop through it in PHP?

Tags: jquery

In jquery I build an 2 dimensional Array. With an ajax call I send the array together with some other variables to update.php to update a MySQL database.

But in the update.php I will loop through the 2 dimensional array, but how can I do that? I try a lot of options but it won't work.

```
   mediaIdsArray.push({             // Push 2D array
    'id_media' : id,
    'bijschrift' : bijschrift').val()
   });
```

Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
    url : 'pages/update.php',
    method:'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data:{
        publish:publish,
        id:id,
        title:title.trim(),
        content:content.trim(),
        mediaIds: mediaIdsArray                    // 2 dimensional array
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Update error');
    },
    success:function(data){
        //alert(data);
    });
```

When I fill the mediaIdsArray above as an 1 dimensional array, I could loop through it with this code:

```
    <?php
      $mediaIdsArray = $_POST['mediaIds'];
      foreach ($mediaIdsArray as $mediaId {
      ...
```

I tried something like $mediaId[0][0] to get the values, but I get null....

Comment: Have you dumped `$mediaIdsArray` at all to see if it actually has anything? Do you actually have anything in your `$_POST` array?

Answer (score 0):

`mediaIdsArray` is an array of objects, not a 2d array. In PHP, `$mediaIdsArray` becomes an array of associative arrays. So you should use named keys of `$mediaId`:

```
foreach ($mediaIdsArray as $mediaId) {
    echo "{$mediaId['id_media']} = {$mediaId['bijschrift']}<br>";
}
```